# Azure internal load balancing

Tags: azure, load-balancing, internal-load-balancer

We are moving from AWS to Azure.

I've deployed four classic VMs using the portal GUI, they reside in a VNet called "vnetdata" in a subnet called "Subnet-01". By deploying them through the GUI, every VM has its own cloud service. I need to internally load balance them over port 5111. The [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-get-started-ilb-arm-cli/) provided shows how to do it for one cloud service having all VMs. How can I merge the VMs into one cloud service? And if I do create the load balancer using CLI, what (or where) is the DNS name or the endpoint for the load balanced service?

Comment: The documentation is for new resource manager vm's, but you have classic vm's. Maybe recreate the vm's in the new model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cbernier/2013/11/11/load-balance-virtual-machines-in-windows-azure/

Basically one may use the classic portal to do this. Using the CLI lead me nowhere as well as the new portal.

UPDATE:
This has been helpful. However using the classic portal, one cannot load balance internally, it is always exposed to the internet. Moreover, Microsoft seems to have abandoned the classic portal, and one cannot assign an ACL to a load-balanced port as it shows "Internal Server Error". I would recommend anyone to use resource manager mode, or actually to move to AWS or other reliable service that understands backward-compatibility